# xcode: no launchable executable at path

Tags: xcode, ipad, debugging

I changed location of my app,which is causing me this error,my release runs, but debug it builds and gives me no launchable executable at path.

How to change path, my app name is correct in all configurations?

Comment: Have you tried deleting and reinstalling the app??? or Clean and then build./???

Answer (score 0):

I develop with several devices. If I do not stop the process before unplugging I have seen this problem after plugging in another device and trying to run it.  I just have to stop and start, sometimes I have to clean and then run.